# k non-attacking rooks on a chessboard with forbidden positions

Tags: combinatorics, polynomials

[Barbeau, Polynomials, page 8]

I am trying to understand the equation shaded in the extract below:

[image]

Unfortunately [the wikipedia entry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rook_polynomial) only has complete boards (all squares allowed)

Now for some handwavy thinking on that equation shaded:

1- if S becomes forbidden, then we have chessboard $C_1$ by definition, and the polynomial for that is $R(C_1,t)$  , also by definition.

2- if S is allowed, then let us put a rook on it. This means the  corresponding row and column becomes off-limits for the remaining rooks (since they must be non-attacking) , effectively giving the reduced $(m-1)(n-1)$ chessboard $C_2$ on which we have 1 fewer rook to place. The polynomial for chessboard $C_2$ with the reduced number of rooks is $R(C_2,t)$ by definition.

3- The polynomial $tR(C_2,t)$ then corresponds to a $mn$ chessboard for which the entire row and column of S is shaded (?)

At this point, I am not so sure:

- about that last statement (3)
- even so, why the two chessboards $C_1$ and $C_2$ are in distinct union to chessboard $C$ (resp. why the 2 polynomials $tR(C_2,t)$ and $R(C_1,t)$ add up to $R(C,t)$ )

Comment: Thinking about this further, i think it is best to initially ignore the polynomial aspect of the question, think in terms of a recurrence relation, in the way this previous question does, and  deduce the polynomial relation therefrom : https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/708523/number-of-ways-to-place-k-non-attacking-rooks-on-an-m-times-n-chessboard?rq=1

Answer (score 1):

> 1- if S becomes forbidden, ...
>
> 2- if S is allowed, then let us put a rook on it. ...

IMO this is thinking about it backwards. The forwards reasoning is: either we put a rook on it (and then we delete the row and column because that's easier than forbidding all the squares in the row and column) or we don't put a rook on it (and we mark it as forbidden to ensure that we don't undo that decision later).

Otherwise, points 1 and 2 look fine to me.

---

> 3- The polynomial $tR(C_2,t)$ then corresponds to a $mn$ chessboard for which the entire row and column of S is shaded (?)
>
> At this point, I am not so sure:
>
> about that last statement (3)

I don't even know what you mean by statement (3). What does "shaded" mean?

I would replace statement (3) with

3b - the polynomial $tR(C_2, t)$ then gives the polynomial for the chessboard $C$ when there is a rook on S.

The key observation is that you multiply the expression from point (2) by $t$ as a way of counting the rook.

---

> even so, why the two chessboards C1 and C2 are in distinct union to chessboard C (resp. why the 2 polynomials tR(C2,t) and R(C1,t) add up to R(C,t) )

Because either there is a rook on S or there isn't. The two options are exclusive and exhaustive.